# PHP Mysql select is only showing one row

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to make a page of a TV series. Somehow the page only shows one row for `seasons`, which are 5 in my database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `shows` WHERE url='".dburl($_GET["url"])."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // General info about the TV show here

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM seasons WHERE `show`='".$row["id"]."' ORDER BY number ASC";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($seasons = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            // The seasons

                $sql= "SELECT * FROM episodes WHERE `show`='".$row["id"]."' AND `season`='".$seasons["number"]."' ORDER BY number DESC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($episodes = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        // The episodes, sorted by season

                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any change I overlooked something? The `episodes` part works just perfectly fine, it shows all the episodes that are in a season.

Comment: Please this code is very very bad, try not to do queries inside queries and inside queries and loops like you are doing, that is real poor performance, If you are getting information from different tables that are related by some field use JOIN that is a native SQL operator https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html and please try not to use mysql but mysqli and prepared queries http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php your queries are easy hackeable as you are using a url parameter without proper validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to get all the data in one mysql query, use proper variable escaping and the code will be simpler and more readable than the one you got. Then maybe you are gonna make fewer mistakes but having better coding:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `shows` sh
         JOIN `seasons` se.show ON sh.id
         JOIN `episodes` e ON e.show = se.id AND e.season = e.number
         WHERE url=?
         ORDER BY se.number, e.number";

  /* Prepare statement */
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->errno . ' ' .$conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  }

   /* Bind parameters. Types: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
   $stmt->bind_param('s', dburl($_GET["url"]));

  /* Execute statement */
  $stmt->execute();

  /* Fetch result to array */
  $res = $stmt->get_result();
  while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     array_push($a_data, $row);
  }

  /* close statement */
  $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Justification or explanation:

> Never concatenate or interpolate data in SQL
>
> Never build up a string of SQL that includes user data, either by
>   concatenation:
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";
>
> or interpolation, which is essentially the same:
>
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
>
> If '$username' has come from an untrusted source (and you must assume
>   it has, since you cannot easily see that in source code), it could
>   contain characters such as ' that will allow an attacker to execute
>   very different queries than the one intended, including deleting your
>   entire database etc. Using prepared statements and bound parameters is
>   a much better solution. PHP's [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) functionality includes this feature (see
>   below).

From OWASP: [PHP Security Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `$result` variable used by the outer loop. Just use a new variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM seasons WHERE `show`='".$row["id"]."' ORDER BY number ASC";
$seasons_result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($seasons_result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($seasons = $seasons_result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: Altough it answer the question and that is the real problem I suggest to penalize this kind of bad coding so no other copy this kind of idea. One mysql query is needed to get all the information then just looping through an array not nested looping with queries, I do not even mention he is not escaping variables, this is really bad programming

Comment: It is not personal Hugo I just want you to know how the best approach will be and I belive you should learn the best practices first so you do not get used to bad practices